# getElementById with ie9

Tags: internet-explorer, getelementbyid

I get an error on the last line using getElementById. What gives?

```
import win32com.client as client

import time

ie = client.Dispatch('InternetExplorer.Application.1')

ie.Visible = 1

ie.Navigate('www.myweb.it') 

while ie.Busy:
time.sleep(0.1)

while ie.Document.readyState != 'complete':
time.sleep(0.1)

click = ie.Document.getElementById('some_id').click() # here goes in error
```

Comment: Have you tried `ie.Document.getElementById('some_id').onclick()` ?

Comment: What language is this? And what is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

It should Work.

```
 Ex.function test()
    {
        var hyperlink = document.getElementById('nameofid');
        hyperlink.onclick = "your code";
    }
```